# Having problems connection to Samsung Mobile Innovator

Tags: windows-mobile, mobile

I am new to all this and I tried to connect to one of the phones. I choose a Windows mobile phone and hit start, I passed all the tests and it started to download the java file.

Once it loads up the lab software though it dies I get this error

Connection Error
Incompatible software version installed on the phone, please upgrade it first

So not sure what to do.

Anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the error to mean that the firmware on the phone isn't recent enough.

It is common practice for mobile software developers to connect a phone to a computer via a USB cable and upgrade the handset firmware using PC software provided either by the Mobile Network Operator the phone is locked to, by the handset manufacturer or by the mobile operating system developer.

EDIT:

a simple MIDlet cannot be run directly on a computer. You need a J2ME emulator running on the computer to execute MIDlets.

The [Sun Ltd](http://java.sun.com) J2ME SDK contains an emulator, as does Netbeans.

[Microemulator](http://www.microemu.org) is a popular open source J2ME emulator.

Comment: Are you saying this software runs on an actual device? I thought this is like an emulator?

Comment: My understanding of your question is that you get an error message when you try to install a MIDlet from the Samsung website onto an actual windows mobile phone.

Comment: No I tired to run the midlet on my computer. I thought it is an emulator so I did not bother to plugin the phone.